# JavaScript - adding up the value of children

Tags: javascript, count, nested, children

I have a JavaScript array of objects, something like this:

```
[{
    name: "Root 1",
    countCases: 0,
    children: [
        {
            name: "Root 1.1",
            countCases: 3
        },
        {
            name: "Root 1.2",
            countCases: 1,
            children: [
                {
                    name: "Root 1.2.1",
                    countCases: 3
                },
                {
                    name: "Root 1.2.2",
                    countCases: 1
                },
                {
                    name: "Root 1.2.3",
                    countCases: 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: "Root 2",
    countCases: 0,
    children: [
        {
            name: "Root 2.1",
            countCases: 3
        },
        {
            name: "Root 2.2",
            countCases: 0,
            children: [
                {
                    name: "Root 2.2.1",
                    countCases: 3
                },
                {
                    name: "Root 2.2.2",
                    countCases: 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

I would like to add up the value of "countCases" of all nested children. To these values were:

```
Root 1 - 9
Root 1.1 - 3
Root 1.2 - 6
Root 1.2.1 - 3
Root 1.2.2 - 1
Root 1.2.3 - 1
Root 2 - 7
Root 2.1 - 3
Root 2.2 - 4
Root 2.2.1 - 3
Root 2.2.2 - 1
```

So every parent has their "countCases" and added "countCases" of all his children. Thank you in advance for your help.

@edit: I tried something like this, but it's not work:

```
 function addCountCasesToParentFromChildren(data)
 {
    var sumCountCases = 0;
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
       sumCountCases = value.countCases;
       if (value.children != '')
       {
          value.countCases += addCountCasesToParentFromChildren(value.children);
       }
    });

    return sumCountCases;
 }
```

@edit2: ok, i did it. It's solution:

```
 function addCountCasesToParentFromChildren(data)
 {
    var sumCountCases = 0;
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
       if (value.children != '')
       {
          value.countCases += addCountCasesToParentFromChildren(value.children);
       }

       sumCountCases += value.countCases;
    });

    return sumCountCases;
 }
```

Comment: Just a matter of recursive traversal. Did you try anything?

Comment: I tried something like this:
         function addCountCasesToParentFromChildren(data)
         {
            var sumCountCases = 0;
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
               sumCountCases = value.countCases;
               if (value.children != '')
               {
                  value.countCases += addCountCasesToParentFromChildren(value.children);
               }
            });

            return sumCountCases;
         }

Comment: Your array notation is not JavaScript (`=>` means something else in JavaScript, and array indexes start at 0, not 1).

Comment: it was only quickly example

Comment: Then the answers wont be that quick...

Answer (score 0):

You could use this ES6 function:

```js
function aggregate(data) {
  return (data || []).reduce( (acc, obj) => {
    var childAcc = aggregate(obj.children);
    var res = {
      name: obj.name,
      sumCountCases: obj.countCases + childAcc.sum
    };
    return {
        arr: acc.arr.concat([res], childAcc.arr),
        sum: acc.sum + res.sumCountCases
    };
  }, {arr: [], sum: 0});
}

// sample data
var data = [{
    name: "Root 1",
    countCases: 0,
    children: [{
        name: "Root 1.1",
        countCases: 3
    }, {
        name: "Root 1.2",
        countCases: 1,
        children: [{
            name: "Root 1.2.1",
            countCases: 3
        }, {
            name: "Root 1.2.2",
            countCases: 1
        }, {
            name: "Root 1.2.3",
            countCases: 1
        }]
    }]
},
{
    name: "Root 2",
    countCases: 0,
    children: [{
        name: "Root 2.1",
        countCases: 3
    }, {
        name: "Root 2.2",
        countCases: 0,
        children: [{
            name: "Root 2.2.1",
            countCases: 3
        }, {
            name: "Root 2.2.2",
            countCases: 1
        }]
    }]
}];

// convert
var { arr, sum } = aggregate(data, 0);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: `Array#reduce` is ES5 :)

Comment: @Leo, Yes. Arrow functions and destructuring are not.